# Laravel: How to create table with case sensitive column (binary)?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, case-sensitive

I would like to use base62 unique identifiers and my problem is that the columns are not case sensitive, so F1 is the same as f1 when I search for it. Now in MYSQL I would simply do

```
CREATE TABLE USERS
(
USER_NAME STRING(10) BINARY
)
```

So in Laravel it should look like

```
$table->string('base62_id', 10)->binary();
```

However, I don't think ->binary() exists in laravel for this purpose. So how would I do that?

Comment: `DB::statement("ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD binary(10) AFTER id");`. You're using MySQL, there's no need to be afraid of MySQL specific DDL. Laravel's `binary` is MySQL's `BLOB`, which is a variable-length column instead of fixed-length column.

Comment: Hm, but I don't think this is what I am asking for. I am telling the column to be a case sensitive string, not "BLOB". I would like to use it as an ID that shouldn't be any longer than 10 characters

Comment: You realize that `binary` means there's no character set, hence there's no case sensitivity. You save *bytes*, not *strings*. `f1` or `F1` is a hexadecimal number represented as something you can read. There's no notion of uppercase F or lowercase f. If you're going to save something to a binary column, that should be binary data, an example being `UNHEX(SHA1('test'));`. If you don't need binary, and apparently you don't, why don't you simply use a `char`?

Comment: Because 'char' is not case sensitive?

Comment: Ok, what I gathered so far - you don't want a `BLOB` (that's fine). You want a `binary`. I show you how to add a `binary` column, but you say that's not what you want (weird, but ok, that was exactly what you asked for). I suggest that you use char, but you have case sensitivity issue so you need a binary one (which is just fine). What exactly do you want then? I literally gave you the SQL that you copypaste into your migration to get a binary column which is 10 chars long, but hey, that's not what you want, you want case-sensitive 10 char long column. I'm confused right now to say the least:)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I found a solution (see below). All I really wanted was a case sensitive column (where I can add an index). Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution! Just a note, as it appears you *can't* add an index to a binary column reading your comment - you **can**, so for future readers who read this - bear that in mind :) have a nice day!

Comment: Oh, I was reading you can't somewhere. I edited my answer, thank you! So I could've just used "ADD `base62_id` VARCHAR( 10 ) BINARY" instead as well?

Comment: Yes, that's right. you could have. Just bear in mind that `varchar` is variable length column. `varchar` counterpart is `varbinary`, `char`'s counterpart is `binary`. If you are 100% sure you will always have 10 characters in your column then use `char` or `binary` type since using `varchar` or `varbinary` would add 1 byte to the length.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this question is old, but in case anyone stumbles upon it. At time of writing, Laravel is version 8 and this is valid:

```
$table->string("case_sensitive_id")->charset("utf8")->collation("utf8_bin")->nullable();
```

This will achieve case sensitivity without any sort of alter statements.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the answer:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD `base62_id` VARCHAR( 10 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin UNIQUE AFTER `id` , ADD INDEX ( `base62_id` )");
```

The key is to use

```
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
```

to make it case sensitive.

Thank you @ my source: http://blog.birdhouse.org/2010/10/24/base62-urls-django/comment-page-1/